# Can I ask Tmux to immediately exit copy mode and paste the content when I yank?

Tags: tmux

I am using vi mode for my tmux. I mapped 'enter copy mode' to M-0. This is really convenient: just my left thumb on left-Alt and my right ring finger on 0

after that , i navigate with vi keys. When I reach my target location, I type v to enter selection mode; then I select a few words, and type 'y', which yank the selected region into tmux's clipboard.

Now comes the complication: I need to type Ctrl-a then ] to paste the selected region. This is unnecessary, because in command line we always paste immediately the position when we enter copy mode. So the Ctrl-a ] is completely redundant.

Is there a way to override 'y' so that it does two things: first yank the region, second, immediately quit copy mode and paste the selected region to the position where I enterred copy mode.